# How do I filter on md-menu-container-class?

Tags: angularjs, class, md-autocomplete

I needed to make a condition to put the class or not, however the md-autocomplete does not allow. Does anyone know how to do it? I have tried to pass from controller to view, but it seems that this property only accepts string and runtime change does not work.

```
    <md-autocomplete md-input-name="{{::filter.id}}"
       md-menu-container-class="autocomplete-custom"
             ...
```

Comment: There is not enough code to replicate the issue, please provide more code, if possible a JSFIddle with the issue.